# HTML & JavaScript. Trying to target a text input from an adjoining anchor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an HTML table. On the table I have an input textbox. Next to it. (appended in the HTML) I have an anchor. All I want the anchor to do (at the moment), is get and set the value in the textbox.

Here is my (abbreviated code) HTML Code:

```
<tr>
  <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DEPARTMENT">
    <input type="text" name="f02" size="20" maxlength="2000" value="" col_name="DEPARTMENT" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text" autocomplete="off" />
    <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DESCRIPTION">
      <input type="text" name="f03" size="20" maxlength="2000" value="soup" col_name="DESCRIPTION" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text" autocomplete="off">
      <a href="javascript:get_desc( $(this).closest('tr') );" class="a-Button a-Button--popupLOV">
        <span class="a-Icon icon-popup-lov">
                            <span class="visuallyhidden">List</span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <input type="hidden" id="fcs_0001" name="fcs" value="FB0D0992B787C5475D897B224F1FAE9D7547BC497FADE2E32B252FFAE2F31CE235225E0D645509C8E3576895FB814229B832CBF0BC11DA3F784FDE9BD5ADED86" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="hidden" id="fcud_0001" name="fcud" value="U" autocomplete="off" />
</tr>
```

Notice I have an input type=text name=f03 with a value of "soup"  (I've also given it another attribute to try and target it. (col_name="DESCRIPTION")

Then under it, I have an anchor which calls a JavaScript function and passes in the current row.

My simple function does the following:

```
function get_desc(thisRow) {

  console.log(thisRow); 
      
  var desc = thisRow.find("input[name='f03']");
  console.log(desc);
  console.log(desc.val()); 
  console.log(desc.text());    
}
```

So it passes in the current row, looks for the input, then tries to get the value.

[image]I can see on console.log that the correct selector is found, but nothing I do gets the value.

As I say, I have lots of JavaScript code in my app, so I've been staring at this wondering what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `desc.length === 0` - so your selector is not working - `console.log($("rubbish"))` will still log a jquery object  **edit** `thisRow.length` is also ==0 so the issue is likely in the `<a href=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some debugging shows that `this` is the `window` object when you use `<a href="javascript:get_desc(this);"`, :

```js
function get_desc(link) {
  console.log(link === window);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:get_desc(this);">click me</a>
```

If you must use html attributes, then you can use `onclick='get_desc(this)`:

```js
function get_desc(link) {
  thisRow =  $(link).closest('tr') 
  var desc = thisRow.find("input[name='f03']");
  console.log(desc.val()); 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="f03" value="soup">
      <a href="javascript:return false;" onclick="get_desc(this);">click me</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Alternatively, embrace jquery events (or vanilla events)

```js
$(".link").click(function() { 
  thisRow =  $(this).closest('tr') 
  var desc = thisRow.find("input[name='f03']");
  console.log(desc.val()); 
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="f03" value="soup">
      <a href="javascript:return false;" class='link'>click me</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used querySelector instead of find and value property of input.

```js
function get_desc(thisRow) {

  console.log(thisRow);

  var desc = thisRow.querySelector("input[name='f03']");
  console.log(desc.value);

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="get_desc(this);">
    <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DEPARTMENT">
      <input type="text" name="f02" size="20" maxlength="2000" value="" col_name="DEPARTMENT" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text" autocomplete="off" />
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="DESCRIPTION">
        <input type="text" name="f03" size="20" maxlength="2000" value="soup" col_name="DESCRIPTION" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--text" autocomplete="off">
        <a href="#" class="a-Button a-Button--popupLOV">
          <span class="a-Icon icon-popup-lov">
          <span class="visuallyhidden">List</span>
          </span>
        </a>
        <input type="hidden" id="fcs_0001" name="fcs" value="FB0D0992B787C5475D897B224F1FAE9D7547BC497FADE2E32B252FFAE2F31CE235225E0D645509C8E3576895FB814229B832CBF0BC11DA3F784FDE9BD5ADED86" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" id="fcud_0001" name="fcud" value="U" autocomplete="off" />
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of href use onClick attribute of anchor.

Try this;

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:get_desc( $(this).closest('tr') );" class="a-Button a-Button--popupLOV">
```